# How to get views relative position on different device sizes

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, uiimage

I have a UImageView which fits to almost entire device size (width/height) and it has a image which is aspect fit. One uiimageview is added on top of background UIImageView at some CGPoint.

Now If we wanted to draw the same scene on different device which has different sizes (iPhone all sizes and iPad) . How to position or how to calculate relative postion of UIImageview on background uiimageview to look exactly same as first device.

Note - Autolayout is not used here

Comment: Can you give an example with each view's `origin` and `size` specified?

Comment: @MedoPaw Background imageview  - (0,0,375,494) and imageview on top has rect - (40,120,60,60)

Comment: You can calculate the frame of the views on different device using the width and height of main screen, with proper proportion.

Comment: @MedoPaw do you have an example ?

Comment: @user2029250 - your question doesn't really make sense... If you are **setting the frame** of background image view to `(0,0,375,494)`, that's the size it will be on every device, and your "image view on top" rect doesn't need to change.

Comment: @user2029250 Given screen width and height, calculate each view's frame, and set the frames. The details of this calculation is up to you, like do you want the origin of a view to be a fixed position no matter how the screen size changes, or do you want it to be proportional to the screen?